# How to externalize application.properties in Tomcat webserver for Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties
>   files in the following locations and add them to the Spring
>   Environment:
>
> ```
> - A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - A classpath /config package
> - The classpath root
> ```
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations
>   higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Question: when running a `war` file on a `tomcat` server: how can I add an additional location for the `application.properties` **outside** the classpath or the tomcat container, like `d:\application.properties`?

The custom location should get highest precedence regarding the locations above.

Problem is: I could of course add a `/config` folder inside my exploded war in the tomcat `webapps` folder, but then I'd lose any custom configuration if the webapps folder is cleaned and war is redeployed.

Thus I'd like to add an additional location outside.

Comment: have you tried putting `application.propeties` on the Tomcat classpath?

Comment: But if I have multiple `war` files, and each one having a `application.properties`, where would I put them, without overriding each other?

Comment: You can provide the external file location while starting the jar.
`java -jar myproject.jar -spring.config.location=D:/application.properties`

Answer (score 27):

For me the easiest way to do it, was to place a context file inside Tomcat's config folder. For example if your application is running under root path (eg. `http://your_domain.com/`) you need to create a file `[path_to_your_tomcat]/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`. If your application runs in a different path, for example `http://your_domain.com/example_path` the file should be named like this `[path_to_your_tomcat]/conf/Catalina/localhost/example_path.xml`. Inside this file you can specify a path to the external application.properties file that can be placed anywhere on your hard drive.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Environment name="spring.config.location" value="file:/path/to/your/application/properties/file/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 17):

You can set a `spring_config_location` environment variable pointing to the folder that contains your application.properties file.

In the case of Tomcat you can do this by adding the following line to your `<TOMCAT_HOME>/bin/setenv.sh` file (create the file if missing):

```
export spring_config_location=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/
```

Place the properties file in that folder. In case you have multiple apps you can set the name of the properties file of each app to be unique. For a Spring Boot App I have done it like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "my-app");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This will pick the new name when run with BOOT. To have the name configured when deployed on Tomcat too, overwrite configure of `SpringBootServletInitializer` like so:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class).properties("spring.config.name: my-app");
    }

}
```

Then name your properties file like: `my-app.properties`. Instead of the default name Spring will look for that. You can put all your apps properties files in the specified folder, `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/` in our sample. Your external properties will get precedence. See here for priorities: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

**UPDATE**

Since **Spring Boot 2** the behavior of `spring_config_location` has changed (from the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location)):

> it previously added a location to the list of default ones, now it
>   replaces the default locations. If you were relying on the way it was
>   handled previously, you should now use
>   spring.config.additional-location instead.

So based on your use case you should consider which of the properties to set as an environment variable. The new one should look like `spring_config_additional-location` in `setenv.sh`. 
Where files are looked up from is described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) too.

Comment: using this i am not able to genearte war file.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot / Spring are you using? Since Boot 2 they have changed the behavior of "spring_config_location". I have updated my answer to cover the latest version too. If that is not the case what error do you get?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Spring Boot 2, I'm trying to use "spring_config_additional-location" as an ENVIRONMENT variable but spring doesn't recognize it. The name of the variable that I have created is "SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION" but it seems that spring, at startup, doesn't take care of it. What is the correct way to set up this variable spring_config_additional-location in a Linux OS ?

Comment: Between ADDITIONAL and LOCATION, instead of an underline ("_") it should be a hyphen ("-"). So the variable should be named SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION. Both upper and lower case work.

Comment: For Windows machine the file will be a batch file<TOMCAT_HOME>/bin/setenv.bat and export will be replaced by Set

Answer (score 2):

In tomcat/bin create setenv.sh file and in file you need to give below line in file for default properties for all the wars, And save it and restart tomcat.

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it several times and the best approach I found is to configure an external directory as classpath resource in the container:

[image: Tomcat classpath]

Then, in the directory place the resources you want to externalize and everything will run fine. To load the resource in spring, you could do this way:

```
<beans:bean id="externalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:[my-application-name]/applicationProperties.properties" />
            <beans:property name="placeholderPrefix" value="!applicationProperties{" />
            <beans:property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
        </beans:bean>
```

You can see that, as you said that you might want to have multiple applications deployed in each tomcat, you could simply create a directory structure in the folder you set in classpath, to maintain different `application.properties` for each of your `war` applications

[image]

In case you want to maintain dinamically the application name section in your Spring configuration, you could do it in several ways, during packaging stage in maven or even using the application context path

Answer (score 0):

I finally added the following property to externalize eg secure properties:

`spring.config.additional-location=/etc/tomcat/<appname>/application-production.properties`

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking for a linux solution, This is working for us:
edit tomcat startup.sh
add:

```
 export spring_config_location=/<YOUR_PATH>/application.properties
```

example:

```
 export spring_config_location=/app/conf/application.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

for tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 and spring boot 2, create setenv.sh file under $CATALINA_HOME/bin/ working for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

export spring_config_additional_location="/opt/tomcat/latest/conf/application.properties"
```

don't forget to set file permission if needed

Answer (score 0):

Using Tomcat `9.0.27`

Running Spring boot `2.2.1`

I did setup `setenv.sh` and added the line

```sh
export spring_config_location=/<PATH_TO_CONF_DIR>/application.properties
```

and got it to work..