# access externalize application.properties in Tomcat for Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, properties, application.properties

i have spring boot application.

i am trying to access application.properties file from tomcat location.

i followed this link : [How to externalize application.properties in Tomcat webserver for Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461786/how-to-externalize-application-properties-in-tomcat-webserver-for-spring)

**MortgageLoanApiApplication**

```
package com.Mortgage.MortgageLoanAPI;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MortgageLoanApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "application");
        SpringApplication.run(MortgageLoanApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ServletInitializer**

```
package com.Mortgage.MortgageLoanAPI;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MortgageLoanApiApplication.class).properties("spring.config.name: application");
    }

}
```

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\bin\setenv.sh**

```
export spring_config_location=C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 8.0.9/conf/
```

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\conf\application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mortgage_loan
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

But when i am running the application or build the application. it is showing error, because it's not finding the db connection.

```
2019-03-04 10:53:28.318  INFO 2872 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-04 10:53:28.325 ERROR 2872 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

> Let me know how to fix this.Or If there is any other way to access
>   properties file from tomcat location using spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access application.properties file from tomcat directory. then we need to follow below steps

Need to add plugin in `pom.xml`. which means it'll ignore the workspace application.properties file after deployment

```
<!-- Added the below plugin to not include the application.properties inside the war -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <packagingExcludes>
            **/application.properties/
        </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Need to copy the application.properties file to tomcat directory `lib` location. then we need to change the `ServletInitializer.java` file.

`"classpath:mortgage-api/"` means we need to create a folder with name `mortgage-api` in tomcat lib folder and will copy application.properties file to this location. check the code comment.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MortgageLoanApiApplication.class).properties(loadproperties());
    }

    /**
     * Added this method to load properties from the classpath while intializing the server app
     * location of the properties file should be inside tomcat directory:
     *    lib/mortgage-api/application.properties
     * @return
     */
    private Properties loadproperties() {
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("spring.config.location", "classpath:mortgage-api/");
          return props;
       }

}
```

then `mvn clean`, then build war file `mvn install`

Answer (score 1):

Please add -

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

or

Use annotation above class -

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: May i know where to use spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration