# Spring Boot add properties on top of current default properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working with a [spring boot application](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/v6.0.3/webapp/resources/bootstrap.properties), in that application there is a config to set spring active profile:

#### {Library}/bootstrap.properties

> spring.profiles.active=standalone

Let say I want to add on top of the above config, so it becomes

#### {My App}/bootstrap.properties (What I current can do)

> spring.profiles.active=standalone,`myprofile`

But I don't want to specified `standalone`, I want to specified the **default properties from the library (i.e. default active profiles from the library)** so I can make sure my property is future proofed.

So I want something like this:

#### {My App}/bootstrap.properties (What I want to achieve)

> spring.profiles.active=`{Library spring.profiles.active}`,`myprofile`

And {Library spring.profiles.active} in the above will translate to `standalone`

Any method the achieve the above? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access externalize application.properties in Tomcat for Spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977186/access-externalize-application-properties-in-tomcat-for-spring-boot-application)

Comment: I have read your link, it is not the same as my question as I want the properties be edited in application.properties of an library, instead of accessing the `application.properties` from Tomcat or other places