# JNDI fails with javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:Name [jdbc/Database] is not bound in this Context when deploying Spring Boot2 Tomcat 9 NO EMBEDDED

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

When I tried to deploy an spring boot application from STS (eclipse) to a tomcat 9 container (embedded server was turn off excluded from pom) using JNDI it fails with the following message:

"javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/Database] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]."

I have done a few things trying to solve it, but problem remains:

- Configure server.xml and context.xml at tomcat/config dir and Server/Tomcat-... in eclipse workspace with the following:
  [Configuration Tomcat (Eclipse and Server configs Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAOBN.png)

My application spring configure is:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    application.profiles("production");
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    builder.profiles("production");
    builder.web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
    builder.run(args); }
```

And datasource config is:
[JNDI Datasource creation source code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k92M.png)

I have tried other possible solutions (like creating context.xml in META-INF dir of app) but nothing works until now, same error is raised:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPe1s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a THIRD place with configuration files in eclipse STS exists and is located in my environment at: .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf , I copy context.xml and server.xml configuration like the images and problem was solved.

Comment: After solving this problem a new one was found: "javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource"  and then I added "factory = “org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory”" to <Resource...> in global <GlobalNamingResources>  at server.xml file and it works like answered here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295503/migration-to-tomcat-8-instancealreadyexistsexception-datasource)